# htaccess regex rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a wordpress website with a cpt called jobs.
i have a jobs archive enabled and the slug is set to 'work-for-us'
currently the url of each job post looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/projects/pfs/work-for-us/job-1/
```

each job will have an apply button and i would like that to be also added into the url above.

i started this by adding a query string 'apply', now my url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/projects/pfs/work-for-us/job-1/?apply
```

the output from the 'apply' query string will show an application form if it exists in the url.

everything above works as it should. the only thing i want to do is to make the url prettier so it doesnt have the '?' and will give me the same output just entering:

```
http://localhost:8080/projects/pfs/work-for-us/job-1/apply/
```

how to do i edit the htaccess file to achieve this.

here is my attempt:

```
RewriteRule ^work-for-us/(.*)/?apply$ work-for-us/$1/apply/ [R,L]
```

my current htaccess file sits in the root of pfs which is the wordpress website:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/pfs/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(work-for-us/[^?]*)\?(apply) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(work-for-us/.+?)/(apply)/?$ $1?$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projects/pfs/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `/projects/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(work-for-us/[^?]*)\?(apply) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(work-for-us/.+?)/(apply)/?$ $1?$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: i am sorry, the actual wordpress website is 'pfs', projects is just parent directory for all my wordpress websites
so i believe i should change the rewrite base to RewriteBase /pfs/ ?>

Comment: i am getting a 'page not found'. any suggestions?

Comment: wordpress was mentioned on the first line of my question, i also tagged it as wordpress

Comment: ok fair enough, post your current WP .htaccess and also tell me in which folder it is

Comment: ok thanks, now are you seeing `http://localhost:8080/projects/pfs/work-for-us/job-1/?apply` gets redirected to `http://localhost:8080/projects/pfs/work-for-us/job-1/apply`?

Comment: the redirect works, however now i am getting a 'page not found' error

Comment: That's right, now after redirect we can't do much in rewrite rules due to the way WP works. Rule#2 above (internal rewrite) won't work with WP. Only 2 ways out are: 1) Use WP rewrite API or 2) Handle it in custom WP 404 handler